# Do we need to restart DataStage Application after to change ODBC.ini?

Tags: postgresql, odbc, datastage

In DataStage 11.7, I have to change the ODBC.ini in the IP ADDRESS field to my PostgreSql.

Is necessary to restart DataStage service for it?

Thanks,
Dinarth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not necessary to restart the DataStage engine when changing the $ODBCINI file, this is dynamic.

On the other hand you will need to restart the DataStage engine if you make changes to the dsenv file.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks alot, man!! I have forgot to ask... 
I have two ODBC.ini.

I have to change IP ADDRESS in two files, correct?
Regards

Comment: Well the one that the DS engine is using is the one identified by the $ODBCINI variable in the dsenv file, not sure why you would have a second one unless you are keeping a copy for backup.

Comment: You are correct!! I changed my IP Address and ocurred like you said!! Thank you, pierre!